# 20.04 Display bug on Macbook 2008; system freezes on change

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 20.04, macbook

I have a Macbook from 2008 (Intel Core2 duo) running Ubuntu 20.04. The primary display (on the laptop screen) is fine, and I'm plugging the external monitor in through a DVI-mini display adapter. The 2nd display (external) comes through, but at the default resolution (1920x1080) is unstable. It's like watching old DVDs with bad compression or connection.

When making adjustments with "Displays", the whole system locks up whenever I click apply. I've rebooted and tried this again, and the same thing has happened about 4 times now. Everytime I try to change anything in Displays with the external plugged in, the system locks up and I have to reboot. With just a the laptop monitor alone, I can make changes.

Seems like a bug with the "Displays" applet. Any suggestions would be welcome.
Here is the output from xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1280x800+1920+280 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 286mm x 179mm
   1280x800      60.22*+  59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00    59.95  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    59.96    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       59.97  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       59.84  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.95    60.00    59.82  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      75.05    60.04    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   960x720       75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    75.00    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       70.08  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I found so far was to install mate

`$ sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`
(During the installation I selected lightdm instead of gdm3. I believe that's the same as the default for ubuntu, so I don't know why this made a difference.)

Then log-out, and log back into a Mate session (which I recommend for lots of other reasons anyway.) I don't know how to resolve this for general GNU sessions, but for me, this totally fixed the display instability, somehow, and I prefer Mate anyway, so I'm happy.